# How to use angular js in my Heroku PHP app?

Tags: php, angularjs, heroku, bigcommerce

I am making Demo Heroku PHP app for Bigcommerce Store. I want to use angular js in this app. Please guide me regarding how can I use angular js in My Heroku PHP app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start your web server (in php) normally and serve for `GET` `/` the `index.html` of the `/dist` angular folder. Your angular project can be a subdirectory of the root project (php) since it's just the view.